# ¿Cómo mostrar una Activity específica solo en la primera ejecución de la Aplicación?

Tags: android, licencias

El caso es que quiero que cuando la aplicación se ejecute por primera vez, se muestre una especie de `LicenseActivity` que muestre la licencia y que cuando el usuario la acepte, se inicie la `MainActivity`. Luego de esto, que ya no vuelva a aparecer dicha `LicenseActivity`.

Comment: Mirate la libreria AppIntro hay un apartado de licencia, donde no deja continuar si el usuario no la activa la casilla.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una preferencia para guardar si tu LicenseActivity fue mostrada:

Al mostrar por primera vez tu Activity verificas si se debe mostrar, y realizas el Intent para mostrar la Activity, al realizar el intent salvas la preferencia con un valor el cual indicará la Activity se mostró:

```
//Obtiene valor de preferencia (la primera ocasión es por default true).
boolean muestra = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext());

//Valida si muestra o no LicenseActivity.
if(muestra){ 
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(myActivity.this, LicenseActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
  saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), false);
}
```

Los métodos requeridos serían:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveValuePreference(Context context, Boolean mostrar) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("license", mostrar);
    editor.commit();
}



public boolean getValuePreference(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getBoolean("license", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar las preferencias en Android, para guardar una variable bandera por ejemplo e inicializarla en false, y al momento de de iniciar el onCreate primero recuperar esa variable y ver en que estado se encuentra si es false, entonces mandas a llamar LicenseActivity, y cuando el usuario acepte la cambiar a True, entonces la siguiente vez que inicie la App ya no llamara esta actividad por que su estado será True. Por lo tanto, iniciara en MainActivity

```
//Declaramos bandera
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("bandera", false);
editor.commit();
```

Para verificar si esta en True o False

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean bandActivity = prefs.getBoolean(bandera, false)
if (bandActivity){}
```

//Cambiamos a true despues de que el usuario acepte

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("bandera", true);
editor.commit();
```

Te dejo el enlace donde encontre esta solución para que puedas apoyarte más. Saludos
[shared preferences sgoliver.net](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/)

Answer (score 2):

Con la siguiente función puedes saber si es la primera vez que usa la app (return 0), si ya la usado antes (return 1) o si se ejecuta por primera vez trás una actualización (return 2)

```
//Retorna: 0 primera vez / 1 no es primera vez / 2 nueva versión
public static int getFirstTimeRun(Context contexto) {
    SharedPreferences sp = contexto.getSharedPreferences("MYAPP", 0);
    int result, currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    int lastVersionCode = sp.getInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", -1);
    if (lastVersionCode == -1) result = 0; else
        result = (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) ? 1 : 2;
    sp.edit().putInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", currentVersionCode).apply();
    return result;
}
```

ahora bien, esto puede ser llamado desde un splash, de la siguiente manera

```
    switch(getFirstTimeRun(this)) {
        case 0:
            Log.d(TAG, "Es la primera vez!");
            // acá haces el intent a tu activity especial
            Intent intento= new Intent(SplashScreen.this, tuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intento);
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d(TAG, "Ya has iniciado la app alguna vez");
            //
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d(TAG, "Es una versión nueva");
            //
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Esto vuelve a 0 si el usuario usa una app de limpieza no es así ?

Comment: claro, ya que usa getSharedPreferences, al igual que las otras 2 respuestas

Comment: he intentado usar tu forma y no me resulta, me aparece siempre por primera vez, cierro la app y nuevamente el mismo mensaje

Comment: que extraño, yo lo uso sin problemas, la única modificación que le hice, es que yo la llamo desde otra actividad, pero no se que puede ocurrir en tu caso

Comment: Apareció que  (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) siempre es false

Comment: pero si es falso, result siempre seria 2.... que te retorna BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE?

Comment: Pero siempre me mostró Es la primera vez ...

Comment: Prueba en tener el instantrun desactivado

Comment: Funciona de maravilla